# How to retain the initial message payload through the flow in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to know if there is any way to retain the initial message payload or part of it along the way in the spring integration channels.

Let's say you have an inbound adapter that pulls some information from a system. This message is passed to another endpoint, which transforms it and most likely you will end loosing some data from it. At some point, you want to use some data from the initial message payload for a router.

Is there any global variable you can hold or a pattern?
Is it like carrying the message payload all the way?
is it like adding the needed data in the message header all the way?

Any idea on this, it will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, typically, the easiest solution is to copy the payload to a header using a header enricher.